# SQL - Select parent-childs recursive

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have 3 tables, one is "Permission" that has columns Id, Name and Permission. This is a role/permission table, if Permission column is null, it is a role, otherwise it is a permission. Another table is Permission_Permission, which has IdParentPermission that is the parent Id and IdChildPermission that is the child Id. And the third and last table is Users_Permissions, that relates users with permissions with columns IdUser and IdPermission.

For example:

Permission

| Id | Permission | Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | DeleteUsers | Can delete users |
| 2 | ChangePassword | Can change password |
| 3 | NULL | Administrator |
| 4 | Listusers | Can view all the users |
| 5 | CreateUsers | Can create new users |
| 6 | NULL | Operator |
| 7 | CreateOffer | Can create a new offer |
| 8 | DeleteOffer | Can delete offers |
| 9 | NULL | Buyer manager |

Permission_Permission

| IdParentPermission | IdChildPermission |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 3 | 4 |
| 3 | 5 |
| 6 | 4 |
| 9 | 7 |
| 9 | 8 |
| 3 | 9 |

Users_Permissions

| IdUser | IdPermission |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 9 |
| 1 | 1 |

In this example, the user with Id 1 has the Administrator role, and the administrator role has all the permissions, but also has the "Buyer manager" role inside. It's like a tree with leaves, and a leaf can be a role or a permission, but a leaf can't be parent of his parent leaf.

What is need is a recursive script to retrieve the permissions/roles of a user with all the childs inside in this way.

| IdUser | IdPermission | Name | Permission | IdParentPermission |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

I have tried a lot in SQL using "with" but no luck so far. This has to be recursive in order to get the roles with all the childs of the desired user, but I couldn't make it.

The data that I have in the database is this:

**Permission**

| Id | Permission | Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | CanLogIn | Can Log In |
| 2 | CanChangePassword | Can Change Password |
| 3 | CanViewUsers | Can View Users |
| 4 | CanCreateUsers | Can Create Users |
| 5 | CanEditUsers | Can Edit Users |
| 6 | CanDeleteUsers | Can Delete Users |
| 8 | NULL | Family 3 |
| 9 | NULL | Admin Role |
| 10 | NULL | RRHH Role |
| 11 | NULL | Test 123 |

**Permission_Permission**

| IdParentPermission | IdChildPermission |
| --- | --- |
| 9 | 1 |
| 9 | 2 |
| 9 | 10 |
| 10 | 1 |
| 10 | 3 |
| 10 | 4 |
| 10 | 5 |
| 11 | 1 |
| 10 | 11 |

**Users_Permissions**

| IdUser | IdPermission |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | 1 |
| 10 | 8 |
| 10 | 9 |
| 15 | 1 |
| 15 | 8 |
| 15 | 9 |

What I have so far is this:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS OFF;

declare @IdUser int = 10;
WITH recursivo AS (
        SELECT sp2.IdParentPermission, sp2.IdChildPermission FROM Permission_Permission SP2
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT sp.IdParentPermission, sp.IdChildPermission FROM Permission_Permission sp 
        INNER JOIN recursivo r on r.IdChildPermission = sp.IdParentPermission
    )
    SELECT DISTINCT IdUser, p.Id, r.IdParentPermission, p.Permission, p.Name
    FROM recursivo r 
    INNER JOIN Permission p ON r.IdChildPermission = p.Id
    INNER JOIN Users_Permissions up on up.IdPermission = p.Id and IdUser= @IdUser
```

Unfortunatelly its not working as expected, only seems to be returning one permission:

| IdUser | Id | IdParentPermission | Permission | Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 1 | 9 | CanLogIn | Can Log In |
| 10 | 1 | 10 | CanLogIn | Can Log In |
| 10 | 1 | 11 | CanLogIn | Can Log In |

Expected results:

| IdUser | Id | IdParentPermission | Permission | Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 1 | NULL | CanLogIn | Can Log In |
| 10 | 8 | NULL | NULL | Family 3 |
| 10 | 9 | NULL | NULL | Admin Role |
| 10 | 1 | 9 | CanLogIn | Can Log In |
| 10 | 2 | 9 | CanChangePassword | Can Change Password |
| 10 | 10 | 9 | NULL | RRHH Role |
| 10 | 1 | 10 | CanLogIn | Can Log In |
| 10 | 3 | 10 | CanViewUsers | Can View Users |
| 10 | 4 | 10 | CanCreateUsers | Can Create Users |
| 10 | 5 | 10 | CanEditUsers | Can Edit Users |

Edit: renamed tables/columns to match english language

Comment: Please show us your desired results.

Comment: Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it. Please read [How to ask homework questions](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822) and [edit] your post.

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you are starting your recursive CTE one level down. You need to start with the base rows, then recurse from there

```sql
DECLARE @IdUser int = 10;

WITH cte AS (
    SELECT up.IdUser, Id = up.IdPermission, IdParentPermission = NULL
    FROM Users_Permissions up
    WHERE up.IdUser = @IdUser

    UNION ALL 
    
    SELECT cte.IdUser, pp.IdChildPermission, pp.IdParentPermission
    FROM cte
    JOIN Permission_Permission pp ON pp.IdParentPermission = cte.Id
)
SELECT
  cte.IdUser,
  cte.Id,
  cte.IdParentPermission,
  p.Permission,
  p.Name
FROM cte
JOIN Permission p ON p.Id = cte.Id;
```

This result obviously returns multiple results for the same permission. For example, permission `1` inherits from `11` which inherits from `10` which inherits from `9`, but this user already has a direct permission for `1`.

To resolve this, you could take the row which uses the lowest recursion.

```sql
DECLARE @IdUser int = 10;

WITH cte AS (
    SELECT up.IdUser, Id = up.IdPermission, IdParentPermission = NULL, Level = 0
    FROM Users_Permissions up
    WHERE up.IdUser = @IdUser

    UNION ALL 
    
    SELECT cte.IdUser, pp.IdChildPermission, pp.IdParentPermission, cte.Level + 1
    FROM cte
    JOIN Permission_Permission pp ON pp.IdParentPermission = cte.Id
),
WithRn AS (
    SELECT
      *,
      rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY IdUser, Id ORDER BY Level, IdParentPermission)
    FROM cte
)
SELECT
  cte.IdUser,
  cte.Id,
  cte.IdParentPermission,
  p.Permission,
  p.Name
FROM WithRN cte
JOIN Permission p ON p.Id = cte.Id
WHERE cte.rn = 1;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/BGeOo66d)

Comment: I tested and it worked, thank you so much! It was harder than I though